# D3.js, csv and foreach undefined value

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying D3.js, and I hava a little issue.
Here is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>
        d3.csv("result-do-nothing.csv", function(error, data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                console.log(d);
                console.log(d.nb);
                console.log(d.memory);
                console.log(d.memory_peak);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is the CSV

```
nb, memory, memory_peak
0,0.809,0.822,
100,0.779,1.072,
200,0.656,1.072,
300,0.656,1.072,
400,0.656,1.072,
500,0.656,1.072,
```

So, when I run the script,

- `console.log(d)` outputs `Object {nb: "0",  memory: "0.809",  memory_peak: "0.822"}` => Nice
- `console.log(d.nb)` outputs `0` => Nice
- `console.log(d.memory)` outputs `undefined` => Why ?
- `console.log(d.memory_peak)` outputs `undefined` => Why ?

I have the same issue with FF and chrome.
I really don't understand why.
BTW, I also try `d['memory']`, rename columns, remove/add the trailing `,` in the csv. Nothing works

**EDIT**: I'm such a noob. There are extra spaces in the csv header: `memory` instead of `memory`

Comment: Are csv files allowed to have random trailing `,` at the end of each data row, with no column header?

Comment: I updated my post. I try to remove the trailling `,`, It did not work. But there is something very strange here: `console.log(d)` works...

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed those spaces too. Oh vell.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept the answer in order to close the question and help other people which might have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are extra spaces in the csv header: `memory` instead of `memory`

Comment: You should accept the answer if it is satisfactory (click on the tick  under the score of the answer)

Comment: I can't for the moment. I have to wait for tommorow ;)